# How to relate two accounts?

Tags: account, relationships

My scenario that i want to achieve is to relate two accounts via a relation ship:

- I'm on an account, and I have to have a related list wich is "Account relationship"
- In this related list : I want to click on "New" and then choose the account i want to link to my current Account, Then choose a relationship between them.
  Result:
- I open "Account 1"
- I create a new relationship , I select "Account 2" and choose as relation "Top office" and save
- In "account 1" I can see in the relationship related liste :
  Account 2 ===== Top Office
- In "account 2" I can see in the relationship related liste :
  Account 1 ===== Branch

Comment: You are aware that account hierarchies are available by standard?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about the standard OOTB feature called [Account Hierarchies](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_hierarchy_setup_lex.htm&type=5).

What you're describing here can be achieved through this.

Hope this helps :)